How can I parse signature value and algorithm from my certificate?
const cert = new crypto.X509Certificate(certificatePem);

// Extract the signature algorithm and signature value from the certificate
const signatureAlgorithm = cert.signatureAlgorithm;
const signatureValue = cert.signature;

Here I'm getting signature value and algorithm as undefined, but I need the correct signature value.

Neither signatureAlgorithm nor signature seem to be defined, see X509Certificate, which explains the undefined. At first glance, I cannot find a property in the docs that directly provides the algorithm or the signature. If you can't find one either, an alternative possibility is x509.raw, which returns the DER encoded certificate. The algorithm and signature can easily be determined from this with an ASN.1/DER parser, e.g. asn1js.
